# CSS When using overflow the gap still remains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a HTML table and when I use overflow to make it sure it doesn't exceed a certain height the below div is placed in such a way that the text could still fit.

I need to the div to be placed directly below the scrolling table.

I am using `overflow: hidden` however I can still select the text, but I can't see it.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
 var $table = $('#ingsNeededTable'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

 $(window).resize(function() {
  colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
   return $(this).width();
  }).get();
  
  $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
   $(v).width(colWidth[i] + 1);
  });    
 }).resize();
 
 var loop = setInterval(function() {
  $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").animate({scrollTop: $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").prop("scrollHeight")}, 100000, "linear");
  $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100000, "linear");
 }, 1);
});
```

```css
#ingsNeededTableHolder {
 height: 45%;
}
#ingsNeededTitle, #ingsRecentTitle {
 text-align: center;
}
#ingsNeededTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}
#ingsNeededTable th, #ingsNeededTable td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#ingsNeededTable thead {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
#ingsNeededTable tbody {
 display: block;
 height: 40%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.ingsNeededTableIng, .ingsNeededTableProd {
 width: 40%;
}
.ingsNeededTableNeeded {
 width: 10%
}
#ingsNeededTable tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #eaf2f1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ingsNeededTableHolder'>
  <table id='ingsNeededTable'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableIng'>Ingredient</th>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>Needed (Kg)</th>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableProd'>Product</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>This Should Be Below The Scrolling Table</h2>
</div>
```

The table is properly aligned on my page, but it isn't on the snippet for some reason.

Comment: Do you want to be able to scroll the table? `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: Sort of, the table should be automatically scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set max-height to `#ingsNeededTableHolder`

```
#ingsNeededTableHolder {
    height: 45%;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
 var $table = $('#ingsNeededTable'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

 $(window).resize(function() {
  colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
   return $(this).width();
  }).get();
  
  $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
   $(v).width(colWidth[i] + 1);
  });    
 }).resize();
 
 var loop = setInterval(function() {
  $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").animate({scrollTop: $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").prop("scrollHeight")}, 100000, "linear");
  $("#ingsNeededTable tbody").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100000, "linear");
 }, 1);
});
```

```css
#ingsNeededTableHolder {
    height: 45%;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#ingsNeededTitle, #ingsRecentTitle {
 text-align: center;
}
#ingsNeededTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}
#ingsNeededTable th, #ingsNeededTable td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#ingsNeededTable thead {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
#ingsNeededTable tbody {
 display: block;
 height: 40%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.ingsNeededTableIng, .ingsNeededTableProd {
 width: 40%;
}
.ingsNeededTableNeeded {
 width: 10%
}
#ingsNeededTable tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #eaf2f1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ingsNeededTableHolder'>
  <table id='ingsNeededTable'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableIng'>Ingredient</th>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>Needed (Kg)</th>
        <th class='ingsNeededTableProd'>Product</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableIng'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableNeeded'>foo</td>
        <td class='ingsNeededTableProd'>foo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>This Should Be Below The Scrolling Table</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I used jQuery instead as the page will be on many different sized screens